# Enable Horizontal Scrollbar in Highcharts with Multiple Pie Charts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I need to enable the horizontal scrollbar when I have more Pie Charts than are visible in the container.  I am able to do this with other chart types by using Highstock.js and the following:

```
scrollbar: {
  enabled: true
},
```

This doesn't seem to work with multiple Pie Charts.  It will squash the Pie if it doesn't quite fit(which I don't want either), but any overflow Charts are hidden.

See my fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/4pn5J/5/

Answer (score 0):

The `scrollbar` only works with stock charts. To get around this, why not make 3 divs inside a "master" div and allow the scrollbar on the div container itself?

EDIT:
[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/2sfwD/) using divs and css. Yes, you are using highstock.js but `scrollbar` is not available on PIE-based charts. Since the xAxis is essentially just he radius of the chart itself.

EDIT2:
[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/CLF2B/) using single div container. You will need to fiddle with the chart sizes. Again done with CSS.

Comment: I'm using HighStock.js for all of my charts

Comment: I would like to avoid that solution as it creates multiple charts menus, etc.  I would like a scrollable container to hold all charts, but still have a single title and menu.  What would be great is .highcharts-series-group with overflow:scroll, but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: Again, PIE is a special case here. The series grouping would have no affect for PIE charts. See update.

Comment: Thanks that's a lot closer, but there are some weird size side effects and charts aren't a uniform size.  Is there a way to disable the automatic scaling?

Comment: I would recommend turning off the data labels and just have them show up on tooltip. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/CLF2B/1/